# MissingResourceException for TimeZoneNames in All API Calls post upgrading to Spring boot 3.1.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, tomcat, java-17

I have upgrade **Spring boot From 2.x to 3.1.1 (Java also upgraded to Java 8 -> Zing Base Java 17)**
Post the upgrade on few nodes following error is observed for all API calls, API calls works find but an additional error response gets appended to the actual response resulting errors
for client

This happens even for **actuator/health** APIs also

API Result

`{"status":"UP"}{"errorCode":"MYAPP-1000","errorMessage":"Can't find bundle for base name sun.util.resources.cldr.TimeZoneNames, locale en_US"}`

Custom Exception Handler Code

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class )
public ResponseEntity handleGenericException(Exception exception) {
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
          .body(cacheRefreshService.buildErrorResponse("MYAPP-1000", exception.getMessage()));
  }
```

Exception StackTrace

```
05:20:51.163 [http-nio-51051-exec-5] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver [] - Failure in @ExceptionHandler com.xxx.api.controller.ApiExceptionHandlingController#handleGenericException(Exception)
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class com.xxx.api.model.ErrorResponse] with preset Content-Type 'application/openmetrics-text;version=1.0.0;charset=utf-8'
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:319) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:245) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:413) [spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:74) [spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:141) [spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:80) [spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.servlet.CompositeHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(CompositeHandlerExceptionResolver.java:55) [spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-3.1.1.jar!/:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1341) [spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1152) [spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1098) [spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) [spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) [spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) [spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) [spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
05:20:51.164 [http-nio-51051-exec-5] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat-1].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServletRegistration] [] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServletRegistration] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name sun.util.resources.cldr.TimeZoneNames, locale en_US] with root cause
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name sun.util.resources.cldr.TimeZoneNames, locale en_US
    at sun.util.resources.Bundles.throwMissingResourceException(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.util.resources.Bundles.loadBundleOf(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.util.resources.Bundles.of(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.util.resources.LocaleData$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.util.resources.LocaleData$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.util.resources.LocaleData.getBundle(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.util.resources.LocaleData.getTimeZoneNames(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleResources.getTimeZoneNames(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.util.locale.provider.TimeZoneNameProviderImpl.getDisplayNameArray(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.util.cldr.CLDRTimeZoneNameProviderImpl.getDisplayNameArray(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.util.locale.provider.TimeZoneNameProviderImpl.getDisplayName(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.util.locale.provider.TimeZoneNameUtility$TimeZoneNameGetter.getName(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.util.locale.provider.TimeZoneNameUtility$TimeZoneNameGetter.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.util.locale.provider.TimeZoneNameUtility$TimeZoneNameGetter.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleServiceProviderPool.getLocalizedObjectImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleServiceProviderPool.getLocalizedObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.util.locale.provider.TimeZoneNameUtility.retrieveDisplayNamesImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.util.locale.provider.TimeZoneNameUtility.retrieveDisplayName(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.TimeZone.getDisplayName(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.subFormat(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.text.DateFormat.format(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.ConcurrentDateFormat.format(ConcurrentDateFormat.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.FastHttpDateFormat.getCurrentDate(FastHttpDateFormat.java:100) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.prepareResponse(Http11Processor.java:967) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.action(AbstractProcessor.java:376) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:208) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:187) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:613) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:334) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:780) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:683) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.Writer.write(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.copy(StreamUtils.java:137) ~[spring-core-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:126) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:44) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:225) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:300) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:245) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.servlet.CompositeHandlerAdapter.handle(CompositeHandlerAdapter.java:58) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-3.1.1.jar!/:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
05:20:51.168 [http-nio-51051-exec-5] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver [] - Failure in @ExceptionHandler com.xxx.api.controller.ApiExceptionHandlingController#handleGenericException(Exception)
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class com.xxx.api.model.ErrorResponse] with preset Content-Type 'application/openmetrics-text;version=1.0.0;charset=utf-8'
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:319) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:245) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:413) [spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:74) [spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:141) [spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:80) [spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.servlet.CompositeHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(CompositeHandlerExceptionResolver.java:55) [spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-3.1.1.jar!/:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1341) [spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1152) [spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1098) [spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) [spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) [spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) [spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) [spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:642) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:410) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:340) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:277) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:358) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:222) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:304) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:149) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
05:20:51.168 [http-nio-51051-exec-5] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver [] - Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class java.util.LinkedHashMap] with preset Content-Type 'application/openmetrics-text;version=1.0.0;charset=utf-8']
```